# Teminal: -bash: ‘alias: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, command

Every time I open terminal or other programming related program I get this output: 
-bash: ‘alias: command not found

What's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Might be some garbage in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile

Comment: My knowledge isn't to big when it comes to the Terminal. What would be the command to remove it?

Comment: Please, this really annoys me.

Comment: just update your question with the content of your .bahrc,  .bash_profile and profile files. hard to say something when we have no information.